# Navigation Bar not showing in View Controller from Navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

currently im using a `SWRevealViewController` to create a sidebar menu, everything is working perfectly except that I have several navigation controllers with their respective rootViewController in which they have a navigation bar but when I simulate it the navigation bar does not show up in any of the viewControllers except the first one where the app starts. I've also done this `navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false` but it does not show up yet.

By the way if you can notice i'm pretty new to swift and Xcode :)

Comment: The scenario is after the exact viewcontroller (first one), remaining vc's are not show navigation bar right? Did you use segue on storyboard? or xib?

Comment: if you are use segue on storyboard let try push on segue. The model does not show the sequence flow of navigationbar on every vc's.

Comment: @S.Karthik I used revealViewController push Controller and set controller respectively, and yes on storyboard, what do you mean by let try push on segue? thanks for your help by the way

Comment: cool friend! I mean it push segue (like model segue present).

Comment: @S.Karthik actually I do not understand you that well, can you send me an example of what you are trying to say?

Comment: sure my friend let me give an example..

Comment: @S.Karthik thanks good sir, this is the only thing that i'm struggling with right now

Comment: Did you see that link , I think it gives such clear idea to you . http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/